# Are these brown areas on my dracaena leaves a disease?

Tags: diseases, dracaena

My dracaena has several leaves with this kind of quite big brown areas on them:

[image]

[Photo source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mkG201ZcEnZ2hXZWtvV21FV1k/view?usp=docslist_api)

Does this look like a disease or might it be only bad caring?

I have a [separate post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23608/dracaena-marginata-losing-many-leaves-with-brown-spots) related to falling leaves, but now I see these brown areas on green, seemingly healthy leaves.

Comment: This looks like a newly purchased plant ( from the residue on the leaves) is it?

Comment: It's not newly purchased.