# What is this big plant with long skinny green leaves?

Tags: identification, leaves

I have this large plant that I have owned for over 2 years. What is it? can I have the common name as well as Latin name, thank you.  I am in northern Europe but that probably doesn't matter since it's an indoor plant. Here are a few photos:
[image]

Also is it normal for it to have brown spots on some of the leaves, as well as brown the the edges of the leaves?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is *Yucca elephantipes*. It is a very common house plant (I have one myself, for many years) and easy to [maintain](https://plantcaretoday.com/yucca-plant.html). Don't give it too much water, and dust it off once in while. It can handle long periods of drought, so ideal if you go for long holidays. It can handle shade and direct sunlight.

Brown tips of the leaves are usually a sign of **too** much water.

Comment: Thank you, the plant gets plenty light and sometimes direct sunlight, I water it about once a week depending on how dry the soil is. And yes I will dust it off as soon as I can, I've been so focused on fixing up my other plants I haven't really had time for this guy. Would you also say that the brown spots on the leaves and base of the leaves are also a sign of over watering? I don't have many brown tips, only a few on the lower leaves.

Comment: In general these plants need very little maintenance, that's why they are so popular as house plant. The brown spots look like [fungus](http://donsgarden.co.uk/pests/37) infection, I am not sure though I never had this. If you want to be sure you can remove the leaves, the plants won't miss them, but don't know how esthetic that will be.

Comment: I removed the leaves, there were about 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit like a Dracaena marginata. There are some photos on [this question about caring for one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/why-have-the-leaves-of-my-dracaena-marginata-completely-fallen-off). These are sometimes called a Dragon Tree.

It might also be a Dracaena fragrans massangeana which is commonly called a corn plant.